# moment-timezone return different date in local and server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, debian, momentjs

i have this function to get date ISODate mongo in timezone

```
let dateInLocal = moment(date, 'YYYYMMDD_HHmmss')
let dateToStore= moment.tz(dateInLocal, 'Europe/Paris').toDate()
```

In my local machine i got :

```
2019-02-01T11:00:00.000Z
```

And on my prod server i got :

```
2019-02-01T12:00:00.000Z
```

What's wrong ? Are there any config to do on server (debian 9)

Answer (score 0):

I inspected my server and it'd set on UTC timezone that's why the result is different, but why moment-timzone is based on machine timezone !!